# Trying to avoid scrollbar return to start after ajaxcall

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm working with FullCalendar, but when I use Ajax to update the state of events that are format conditioning, when I scroll lateral as the ajax is called the scrollbar resets to the start preventing the viewer to stand at the position he wanted to visualize.

I have tried setting a fixed width for the div containing Calendar class, no results maybe I didn't set it right

```js
function ajaxcall1(calendar) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "call for API",
    success: function(doc) {
      successAjax(doc, calendar);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }).done(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      ajaxcall2(calendar);
    }, 4000);
  });
}

function ajaxcall2(calendar) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "call for API",
    success: function(doc) {
      successAjax(doc, calendar);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }).done(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      ajaxcall1(calendar);
    }, 4000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceTimeGrid'],
    resourceGroupField: 'group',
    defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
    displayEventTime: false,
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    height: 700,
    scrollTime: starthour,
    resourceGroupField: 'groupId',
    slotLabelFormat: {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: '2-digit',
      omitZeroMinute: false,
      meridiem: 'short',
      hour12: false
    },
    resources: [{
      id: '1',
      title: 'R16/MOTORES',
      groupId: 'P16'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      title: 'R19/TRANSMISSÃO',
      groupId: 'P19'
    }, {
      id: '3',
      title: 'R26/CHASSIS',
      groupId: 'P26'
    }, {
      id: '4',
      title: 'R27/CHASSIS',
      groupId: 'P27'
    }, {
      id: '5',
      title: 'R40/CABINAS 1',
      groupId: 'p40'
    }, {
      id: '6',
      title: 'R54/CABINAS 2',
      groupId: 'p54'
    }, {
      id: '7',
      title: 'R56/KD',
      groupId: 'P56'
    }, {
      id: '8',
      title: 'TRUCK ON WHEELS',
      groupId: 'P56'
    }],
    nowIndicator: true,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm'
  });

  calendar.render();
  ajaxcall1(calendar);
})

`enter code here`.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
    height: 3.4em;
}

.fc-title {
    font-size: 15px;
}

#erro {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#backDiv {
    background-size: 100% 120%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}
#erro {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}


#warning {
    background-color: #D6001C;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 900 !important;
}
.fc table {
    table-layout: auto;
}

.fc-view > table {
    min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.fc-axis {
    min-width: 70px; /*the width of times column*/
    width: 70px; /*the width of times column*/
}

.fc-day, .fc-resource-cell, .fc-content-col, .data-resource-id {
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

The code of successAjax()

`enter code here`function successAjax(doc, calendar) {

```
        allEvents = [];
        $(doc).each(function (idata) {
         $(location).each(function (iloc) {

                if (location[iloc] == "R16") {
                    allEvents.push({
                        id: idata,
                        resourceId: '1',
                        title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + licenseplate + "\n" + "Entry: " + entrada + "\n" + " - MUs: " + doc[idata].QuantityInside,
                        start: doc[idata].EDA,
                        end: dt,
                        allday: false,
                        backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                        textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                        arrival: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_ARRIVAL_DATE,
                        entry: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_ENTRY_DATE,
                        departure: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_DEPARTURE_DATE,
                        trailerId: doc[idata].TRAILER_ID,
                        description: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY,
                        hour: catchHour
                    });
                } else if (location[iloc] == "R19") {
                    allEvents.push({
                        id: idata,
                        resourceId: '2',
                        title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + licenseplate + "\n" + "Entry: " + entrada + "\n" + " - MUs: " + doc[idata].QuantityInside,
                        start: doc[idata].EDA,
                        end: dt,
                        allday: false,
                        backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                        textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                        arrival: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_ARRIVAL_DATE,
                        entry: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_ENTRY_DATE,
                        departure: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_DEPARTURE_DATE,
                        trailerId: doc[idata].TRAILER_ID,
                        description: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY,
                        hour: catchHour
                    });
                } else if (location[iloc] == "R26") {
                    allEvents.push({
                        id: idata,
                        resourceId: '3',
                        title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + licenseplate + "\n" + "Entry: " + entrada + "\n" + " - MUs: " + doc[idata].QuantityInside,
                        start: doc[idata].EDA,
                        end: dt,
                        allday: false,
                        backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                        textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                        arrival: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_ARRIVAL_DATE,
                        entry: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_ENTRY_DATE,
                        departure: doc[idata].PRU_GATE_DEPARTURE_DATE,
                        trailerId: doc[idata].TRAILER_ID,
                        description: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY,
                        hour: catchHour
                    });
                    ... Input of Events via API
                    try {

            calendar.getEventSources()[0].remove();

        } catch (err)
        {

        }

        calendar.addEventSource(allEvents);
```

The rest are logic to change color of events and relocate the excess of events in a certain hour

Comment: Are you updating the content of calendar after successfull ajax call ?

Comment: There's not enough information here to reproduce the error. It potentially relates to CSS and to the page elements around the calendar, but you haven't included those, and you also haven't included the "successAjax()" function. We need more information please. Are you by any chance deleting and re-creating your calendar every time you run the AJAX? If so, there is really no need to do that. Fullcalendar supports dynamic event sources.

Comment: @Dahou Maybe that's not what you meant but the function successAjax() makes the conditional formatting and it is called after every successfull Ajax.

Comment: @ShengHiu I know maybe i was not clear in my question, i meant if you are updating the content of the html element that is being scrolled, if so this is what is causing scroll offset reset

Comment: My best guess is that in function successAjax you're overwriting the document body or a large div, but you haven't included the contents of that function.  If you overwrite a large element the document will not have a scroll bar, and in the split second that it processes the information it will reset the scroll position.  Try using a library such as Vue or React to replicate elements rather than dumping an html string into a div.  As @Dahou said, when scrolling within an element like a div you'll lose scroll position there as well if you overwrite the div's contents.

Comment: @ADyson I'm not destroying the calendar. I'm removing the Event Source and then adding every successAjax() which is consequence of the success of the Ajax call

Comment: Nonetheless, can you show the code of "successAjax" please, then we have a full picture to try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Dahou it isn't an overflow on the calendar div. The reset is occurring at all page maybe because the calendar is larger than the rest of the div's like MaKR said

Comment: @ShengHiu ok, I dont know the FullCalendar but as workaround you can backup scroll position and set it again after you update calendar data

Comment: Just a follow up @MaKR was right the modification of the calendar sizes surpassed the document body, which kept resetting after every Ajax. The solution was to set html larger than the calendar